# Как закруглить углы кнопки и менять цвет при нажатии в android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть `button.xml` и мне нужно в нем закруглить кнопку и одновременно с этим менять цвета при нажатии. Вот код:

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/button_pressed_color" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/menu_color" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/button_color" />
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Однако оно не работает. Если убрать закругление или обработку нажатия, то все нормально, но вместе нет. Как реализовать эту функцию?

Answer (score 8):

Всё делается довольно просто, и я посоветую поступить именно так, ибо так намного удобнее:

**Укажите стиль для своей кнопки:**

```
<Button
  ..
  style="@style/MyStyle.ButtonMain"
  .. />
```

**Создайте свой стиль в `res/values/styles.xml`:**

```
<style name="MyStyle.ButtonMain">
    ..
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_main</item>
    ..
</style>
```

**Теперь далее, `/res/drawable/button_main.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_main_shape"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_main_shape_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

И уже в этих файлах проводите настройку, как будет выглядеть кнопка в обычном состоянии, при нажатии и так далее, например `button_main_shape.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/button_checked" />
    <corners 
      android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/corner_radius"
      android:topRightRadius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
</shape>
```

Здесь уже указываете все необходимые параметры. Таким образом, вы можете сделать так, чтобы при нажатии и в обычном состоянии кнопки выглядели абсолютно по-разному. 
Могу посоветовать [этот](http://angrytools.com/android/button/) и [этот](http://shapes.softartstudio.com/) сервисы, с помощью которых удобно и наглядно можно создать нужный вам shape.